# [apache-flink]An input of GenericTypeInfo<Row> cannot be converted to Table. Please specify the type of the input with a RowTypeInfo

Tags: exception, apache-kafka, flink-streaming

@Fabian Hueske

I've tried to to specify such a schema, when I read from kafka, and covert inputstream 2 table . But I got the exception:

- Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException:
  An input of GenericTypeInfo cannot be converted to Table. Please
  specify the type of the input with a RowTypeInfo

And the code here:

```
    class WormholeDeserializationSchema(schema: String) extends KeyedDeserializationSchema[Row] {
  //var keyValueTopic:KeyValueTopic = _


  override def deserialize(messageKey: Array[Byte], message: Array[Byte], topic: String, partition: Int, offset: Long) = {
    val deserializationSchema = new SimpleStringSchema()
    val key = if (messageKey != null) deserializationSchema.deserialize(messageKey) else null
    val value = if (message != null) deserializationSchema.deserialize(message) else null
    val ums = UmsSchemaUtils.toUms(value)
    ums.payload_get.map(_.tuple).map(tuple => Row.of(tuple: _*)).head
  }

  override def isEndOfStream(nextElement: Row): Boolean = false

  override def getProducedType: TypeInformation[Row] = {
    val (fieldNameArray, fieldTypeArray) = getSchemaMap(schema)
    val types =new RowTypeInfo(fieldTypeArray,fieldNameArray)
    types
  }

  private def getSchemaMap(jsonSchema: String) = {
    val umsSchema = JsonUtils.json2caseClass[UmsSchema](jsonSchema)
    val fields = umsSchema.fields_get
    val fieldNameList = ListBuffer.empty[String]
    val fieldTypeList = ListBuffer.empty[TypeInformation[_]]
    fields.foreach {
      field =>
        fieldNameList.append(field.name)
        fieldTypeList.append(fieldTypeMatch(field.`type`))
    }
    println(fieldNameList)
    println(fieldTypeList)
    (fieldNameList.toArray, fieldTypeList.toArray)
  }


  private def fieldTypeMatch(umsFieldType: UmsFieldType): TypeInformation[_] = {
    umsFieldType match {
      case STRING => Types.STRING
      case INT => Types.INT
      case LONG => Types.LONG
      case FLOAT => Types.FLOAT
      case DOUBLE => Types.DOUBLE
      case BOOLEAN => Types.BOOLEAN
      case DATE => Types.SQL_DATE
      case DATETIME => Types.SQL_TIMESTAMP
      case DECIMAL => Types.DECIMAL
    }
  }
}



 val inputStream: DataStream[Row] = env.addSource(myConsumer)
 val tableEnv = TableEnvironment.getTableEnvironment(env)
```

(exception here)

Answer (score 0):

The exception is caused by a bug in Flink's type system (see [FLINK-9556](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-9556)). The type information specified in the deserialization schema is not considered in the Scala API.

As a workaround you can always specify the type information manually via:

```
env.addSource(myConsumer)(Types.ROW(...))
```